# orgmode - adjust tikz picture width for beamer output

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In this example, the first column width adjust works but the second column doesn't.

```
* topic
** column1
- first
- second
 :PROPERTIES:
   :BEAMER_col: 0.5
:BEAMER_env: block
   :END:
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.4\textwidth
[[./circle.png]]

** column2
- first
- second
 :PROPERTIES:
   :BEAMER_col: 0.5
:BEAMER_env: block
   :END:
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.4\textwidth
#+BEGIN_SRC latex :file circle.png :eval yes :results drawer :exports results
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\r{2}
\draw (0,0) circle (\r);
\end{tikzpicture}
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
:RESULTS:
[[file:circle.png]]
:END:
```

What's correct way to adjust the tikz output width to :width 0.4\textwidth?

[image]

Comment: The PROPERTIES drawer (for both columns) should be immediately below the headline and before any contents of that headline. Try that to see if it works better.

Comment: Also, the second ATTR_LATEX line should be immediately before the RESULTS, not the src block. But it doesn't work even if you fix these things. Why do you have the results in a drawer?

Comment: @éric Right, after move the line below #+end_src, it works now but orgmode window will not show that image but the text file:circle.png.